# Differentiating the delta function

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I want to proof that:

$$\lim_{a \to 0}\frac{\delta(x+2a)-\delta(x+a)}{a} = \delta'(x)$$

I tried with the definition of differential but I could not end the proof. Any idea?

Comment: What have you tried explicitly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: δ(x) is the dirac delta function

Comment: Do you know how the limit of distributions is defined?

Comment: There's something wrong in the statement you're to prove. Should it be $\delta(x+2a)-\delta(x+a)$? Or should there be a $3$ somewhere?

Comment: Yes it is wrong. Its δ(x+2a)-δ(x+a)

Comment: I edited the question accordingly. Hope this is to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

So here is a proof: Let $\varphi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ be any test function. Then

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \frac{\delta(x+2a)-\delta(x+a)}{a} \right) \varphi(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{\varphi(-2a) - \varphi(-a)}{a}. $$

Now letting $a \to 0$, either by writing $\frac{\varphi(-2a) - \varphi(-a)}{a} = \frac{\varphi(-2a) - \varphi(0)}{a} + \frac{\varphi(0) - \varphi(-a)}{a}$ or applying the L'Hôpital's rule, we can check that

\begin{align*}
\lim_{a \to 0} \frac{\varphi(-2a) - \varphi(-a)}{a}
&= -\varphi'(0)
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta'(x)\varphi(x)\, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Therefore

$$ \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{\delta(x+2a)-\delta(x+a)}{a} = \delta'(x) $$

in the space $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ of distributions.